# c# loop within a loop

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'm currently using DataSets to bring back results in a C# service which I now need to change to loop through the initial set of data and bring back a subset of data from this result.

So I need to loop through these results using an identifier and then show another set of results within a nest below each of these. Using datasets seems no way of making this happen from my limited C# knowledge.

EG> Loop through DB, for each result in DB loop through another table.

```
[WebMethod(BufferResponse=true,Description="Viewing Things")] 
public DataSet MyFunctionIs (int IDtoQuery) 
{ 
  MySqlConnection dbConnection = new   MySqlConnection("server=na;uid=na;pwd=na;database=na;");
  MySqlDataAdapter objCommand = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT STATEMENT HERE;", dbConnection);
  DataSet DS = new DataSet(); 
  objCommand.Fill(DS,"MyFunctionIs");
}
```

But even using joins isnt going to fulfill.. I need to query of each row returned on this and return a child set of data for the XML response

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this?:

    foreach (var row in datasetrows)
    {
    foreach (var subsetRow in GetSubsetDataRows(row))
    {
      // your nested row is the subset row. 
    }
    }

Comment: Can you show the code you have?

Comment: It can be done, but may not be the best choice. What format(s) do you want to use at the service boundary?

Comment: Can you change the original query? Then you can avoid this inefficient looping you talk of.

Comment: `code` [WebMethod(BufferResponse=true,Description="Viewing Things")]
  public DataSet MyFunctionIs (int IDtoQuery) 
  {

    MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection("server=na;uid=na;pwd=na;database=na;");
    MySqlDataAdapter objCommand = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT STATEMENT HERE;", dbConnection);

    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    objCommand.Fill(DS,"MyFunctionIs");
But even using joins isnt going to fulfill.. I need to query of each row returned on this and return a child set of data for the XML response.

Answer (score 0):

Often you can solve this kind of problem by using a SQL query that joins several tables and returns only one set of rows. This gives you a general idea on how you can try to do it:

```
string ConnectionString = "server=myserver;uid=sa;pwd=secret;database=mydatabase";
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    string CommandText = "SELECT p.firstname, p.lastname, o.operderdate " +
                         "FROM persons p LEFT JOIN orders o ON p.person_id = o.person_id";
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, con)) {
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}, {2}", reader["firstname"], reader["lastname"], reader["operderdate"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to be a solution as I need to return a subset of data as it's being used within a web service. So I need a heading set of information and a child set of nodes which are from the sub query.